# Redirecting pre-existing URL to a wordpress permalink url

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I previously had a static website with a page such as www.example.com/pages?id=123

I remade that website into a wordpress site with permalinks such as: www.example.com/Iam-a-url

Now here is my problem, my existing users are visiting www.example.com/pages?id=123 and get a page not found error(because of course it doesnt exist). How do I go about redirecting them to www.example.com/Iam-a-url

Comment: First, at what level you want these redirects? Webserver, PHP, HTML ...?

Answer (score 0):

Place this into your functions.php

```
function _redir_old_site(){
    if( (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'pages?id=') !== FALSE) ){
        //you can set the redirect based on the id
        $oldID = $_GET['id'];
        //set default page id
        $nowID = 5;
        switch( $oldID ){
           case '123':
                //the page id now
                $nowID = 46;
              break;
           //....and so on.....
        }
        header("location:". get_permalink($nowID) );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', '_redir_old_site', 1);
```

good luck! :)